# Permutations with bounded displacement on a circle

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-dynamical-systems

I am interested in references to results on permutations $\sigma$ of $\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$ satisfying $\text{min}\{ \sigma(i)-i\text{ (mod } n),i-\sigma(i) \text{ (mod } n) \} \leq k$ for some $k$ for all $i$. I don't know if there is a common term for these, so I settled for the "bounded displacement" in the title.

I was only able to find two related topics, but both with the linear order, without the "mod $n$" part. These are the band permutations and probabilistic results about them, concerned with random walks (and relaxing the "all $i$" assumption to just "most $i$"), discussed in [this video](https://open.library.ubc.ca/cIRcle/collections/48630/items/1.0221571), and the enumeration problem for permutations with bounded drop (bounding the value of $i-\sigma(i)$ instead) inspired by sorting problems, and solved in [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0195669810000223). It also seems like such permutations might arise with Schreier graphs, but I was unable to find any references, nor analogues of the previous two on the circle.

I am not primarily concerned with counting these permutations (but will be happy to see that too). Ideally, I would like to see dynamical results about such a permutation of a discrete set, or about quantities invariant or bounded under such permutation acting on $\mathbb{R}^n$, since this is the context we encountered them in.

Comment: Given the last paragraph, https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.4736 might be related.

Comment: Let $f_k(n)$ be the number of such permutations. By the technique used to prove Proposition 4.7.10 of *Enumerative Combinatorics*, vol. 1, second ed., if we interpret $f_k(n)$ suitably for small $n$ then $\sum_{n\geq 0}f_k(n)x^n=-xQ_k'(x)/Q_k(x)$ for some polynomial $Q_k(x)$.

Comment: It would be great if you could add this to findstat.org. (I'm on a cellphone right now) here is code:
def statistic(pi):
    n=len(pi)
    return max(min((e-1-i)%n,(i-e+1)%n) for i,e in enumeate(pi))